# using jquery to "destroy" a function

Tags: jquery

I'm using a image zoom in do api. I want to kill it from working when I click on an image.

it's being call like this

```
$('.zoom').zoom();
```

I thinking something along the lines of.

```
$('.zoom').kill(.zoom());
```

Comment: It generally has to be built into the plugin, though you could effectively kill it by doing `$('.zoom').remove();`

Comment: .zoom is a A plugin to enlarge images on mouseover. I want to be able to control when it's running

Comment: .die is the old way of unbinding .live bound events. has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @KevinB : from my reading of the question, the handlers attached by the `zoom()` call need to be detatched or overridden as needed, so `.die()` is relevant, or rather its new incarnation as `.off()`. Destroying the `.zoom()` function would prevent resetting the default zoom behaviors

Comment: @DomDay we can't possibly know how to destroy/undo what .zoom() does without knowing what .zoom() does to begin with. Anything other than asking for information on what .zoom is is irrelevant. For all we know it could be completely replacing the original element with a new one, or creating a dialog, etc.

Comment: @KevinB : Obviously we all try to help. You suggested maybe removing the element would point him in the right direction, Aldi suggested maybe unbinding the existing event handlers might help. Neither is unreasonable while waiting for more information. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to do that, but you can override it this way :

```
$.fn.zoom = null
```

Comment: Will that cause a TypeError though if you try to call it after nullifying it?

Comment: @kyle Yes it will, it would be best to do `$.fn.zoom = function(){}`.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery does not have a `kill` method. You might be able to replace the zoom method with a function that does nothing, i.e.:

```
$(".zoom").zoom = function () {
    return;
};
```

Although doing that would be destructive.

Answer (score 1):

The `zoom()` call will be attaching event handlers to your `.zoom` elements. To turn off these handlers without destroying the zoom functionality, you'll need to call `.off()` .

If you do it this way, you can reactivate them by calling `$('.zoom').zoom();` again.

```
$('.zoom').off();  // to remove all handlers
```

and

```
$('.zoom').zoom(); // to re-enable them
```

Note that calling `.off()` like that will remove all handlers, so if you've added your own handlers, for hover or whatever, you'll need to selectively turn off the zoom handlers  ( most likely `click` )

```
$('.zoom').off('click');  // to remove only the click handler
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it will works for your case or not, but it's fine when I tried in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aldiunanto/buR4n/)

I assume `event()` is `zoom()`

```
$('img').click(function(){
    event();
});
$('button').click(function(){
    $('img').unbind('click');
});
```

Comment: how does .unbind('click') undo what zoom() does?